# When will elasticsearch try to recover its indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fix an issue related to Elasticsearch in our production which is not reproducible always. I am using Elasticsearch 1.5(yet to upgrade).

The issue is that while trying to create an index I get an error with exception IndexAlreadyExistsException because call to

```
client.admin().indices().prepareExists(index).get().isExists();
```

returns false as Elasticsearch is in recovery mode then when I try to create an index I get that exception.

Below are few links to the issues which says that Elasticsearch returns false while recovering indexes.

[8945](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8945)
[8105](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8105)

As I am not able to reproduce the issue always I am not able to test my fix which is to check the health first before checking isExists().

My question is that when will Elasticsearch start recovery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`prepareHealth()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-cluster.html#java-admin-cluster-health) admin method in order to wait for the cluster to reach a given status before doing your index maintenance operations:

```
ClusterHealthResponse health = client.admin().cluster().prepareHealth(index)   
    .setWaitForGreenStatus()                    
    .get();
```

Or you can also wait for the whole cluster to get green:

```
ClusterHealthResponse health = client.admin().cluster().prepareHealth()   
    .setWaitForGreenStatus()                    
    .get();
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that but that is the solution. What I am looking is the answer for when will elastic search try to recover? As of now the issue gets reproducible in production that too only few times. I want to reproduce it locally. Now to reproduce it locally I need Elasticsearch to go in recovery mode but for local installations everything works fine.

Comment: You can then use `RecoveryResponse recoveryResponse = client().admin().indices().prepareRecoveries(index).get();` if you want to artificially trigger the recovery of an index.

Comment: Have you been able to do what you wanted?

Comment: Hey Val,
Sorry for the delay. I tried forcing the recovery using the code you provided but was not able to reproduce the issue locally. On production also the issue gets reproduced only sometime.